# mysql stored procedure multiple rows return

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i Have a problem returning multiple rows in one output

there are **multiple** user_roleID's returned. The procedure is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample(OUT userName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
SELECT user_roleID INTO userName FROM users;
END
```

i would like to get a list of data when i print the output value (userName)

```
call Sample1(@emp);
select @emp;
```

but when i excecute this command i get the following error reported:

> 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Can somebody tell me how to fix this problem?

kind regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retreive multiple rows from stored procedure in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307939/how-to-retreive-multiple-rows-from-stored-procedure-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to create a stored function to return an ID based on a username, for example, then the following would work

```
CREATE FUNCTION Sample(inUserName VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnValue INT;
    SELECT user_roleID INTO returnValue FROM users WHERE userName = inUserName LIMIT 1;
    RETURN returnValue;
END
```

This would be called using `SELECT Sample('SomeUserName') AS userID;`

Comment: thanks the second was where i was looking for. worked fine :)

Comment: You'll never can return more than one row using `LIMIT 1`? So you'd be forced to make as you mentioned `SELECT Sample('SomeUserName') AS userID;` but why than using a function? If I'm not wrong this could be solved with `SELECT user_roleID FROM users where userName = 'SomeUserName'`?

Comment: You can specify to return more rows from LIMIT, however the OP was just trying to get a roleID for a username using a function, which is only able to return a single value, and so the above worked for them.  I am not in a position to know why they chose to do it this way though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store more than one row that way. To return multiple rows you have to define a cursor or return it directly and not storing it locally, if don't manipulate the data:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Sample(inUserName VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT user_roleID FROM users WHERE userName = inUserName;
END
```

Why don't use just SQL instead?