# Error while calling mysql stored procedure that return more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

**I want write a stored procedure that return more than one row.**

My **stored procedure** is (it is only an example)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE get_users(out get_users varchar(30))
BEGIN
    select name into get_users from tbl_join;

END
```

Now I want to call the stored procedure and display result in phpmyadmin.

```
call get_users(@out);
select @out;
```

Then an error occured.

> **#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row**

My table `tbl_join` is:

```
id    name      date

1     Anil     2000-09-12
2     Rahul    2001-02-04
3     Lijin    1999-12-21
```

Expected result is:

```
Anil
Rahul
Lijin
```

Simply I want a **Stored Procedure** for the above result. Please help me..

Comment: Using `into getusers` sets the result into a variable which can only have one value. Simply use `select name from tbl_join`

Comment: @RamRaider, then how to change `out get_users varchar(30)`  part ..

Comment: this might give you some pointers on the way forward. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379007/mysql-stored-procedure-multiple-rows-return?rq=1 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830053/mysql-stored-procedure-error-1172-result-consisted-of-more-than-one-row?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

A query like this

```
select name into get_users from tbl_join;
```

is kind of pointless. In a relational database there is no order unless you specify it. In theory you could get another random row each time you execute this query. Write it like this

```
select name into get_users from tbl_join order by name limit 1;
```

to get the first name in alphabetical order, for example.

Comment: I want to display all rows at a time. `by name limit 1`  gives only one row.

Comment: Well, only one entry fits into a variable. If you want to display the whole table just do a `SELECT * FROM table` and forget this whole stored procedure thing.