# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. for all queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, tomcat8.5

I have mysql 5.5.21 installed and use mysql connector 5.1.44 in my web application running on tomcat 8.5.27.

Recently, I started getting the following exception for all queries (select/insert/update etc) in my webapp after a certain time.

> java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6298)....
```

After I restarted the server, everything started working fine.

Is there any scenario which might cause such behaviour?

Comment: Can you include some sample code from an area which is consistently failing (at least some of the time)?  Hard to guess based solely on your error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a idea from this

[ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035396/resultset-is-from-update-no-data)

If this will not helpful then please provide some sample code.