# Learning store procedures, simple query (IN ... OUT...)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, rdbms

I'm trying to do the following:

```
    # get_all_books_by_author

    drop procedure if exists func;

    delimiter ^^
    create procedure func(in authName varchar(20), out books varchar(255))
    begin
        select book.title
        into books
        from book
        INNER JOIN wrote on wrote.bookcode = book.bookcode
        INNER JOIN author on author.authornum = wrote.authornum    
        where authName = author.authorFirst;

    end ^^
    delimiter ;

call func('Toni', @books); 
select @books;
```

This is me practicing for a test tomorrow, I'm trying to create the procedure so when I put the name of the author on the call, it fetches all the books from him/her.

Tables:

> author: authorNum, authorLast, authorFirst
>
> book: bookCode, title, publisherCode, type, paperback
>
> wrote: bookCode, authorNum, sequence

I created a tuple relational calc for you if that helps:

```
//The E means the existential quantifier 

{ a.title | book(a) AND (Eb)( wrote(b) AND (Ec)( Author(c) AND
b.authornum=c.authornum AND b.bookcode=a.bookcode AND
c.authorFirst='name_of_the_OUT' ))}
```

if there above expression has a mistake please let me know I'm also learning it lol but I think it's correct. What I'm interested is in the sql query itself with the procedure.

I tried this basic SQL and works but I can't get the store procedure to work:

```
select title
from book
INNER JOIN wrote on wrote.bookcode = book.bookcode
INNER JOIN author on author.authornum = wrote.authornum
WHERE author.authorFirst = 'Toni';
```

please help

thank you!

Comment: call get_all_books_by_author - your procedure is called func - is this a transcription error or just an error?

Comment: transcription error, sorry. I just fixed it and I found the solution too, it's below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem, honestly that didn't serve the purpose of my own exercise since I wanted to practice the IN, OUT ... but I guess I learned something even though it wasn't at the right time. 
The problem is that MYSQL assumes that INTO will return only 1 row, and I'm sending more than 1 there, so in this case there are a couple of options:

How to retreive multiple rows from stored procedure in mysql?

> Plan A: Fill another table, it may be a temporary table.
>
> Plan B: Just execute your SELECT statement without INTO clause from
>   the procedure; then you could read data-set from the application (c#,
>   PHP+mysqli,...)
>
> Plan C: Do not use the procedure, just execute the SELECT query.

[Source from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307939/how-to-retrieve-multiple-rows-from-stored-procedure-in-mysql)

This is my final code:

```
# get_all_books_by_author

drop procedure if exists get_all_books_by_author;

delimiter ^^
create procedure get_all_books_by_author(in authName varchar(20))
begin
    select book.title
    from book
    INNER JOIN wrote on wrote.bookcode = book.bookcode
    INNER JOIN author on author.authornum = wrote.authornum  
    WHERE author.authorFirst = authName;


end ^^
delimiter ;

call get_all_books_by_author('Toni');
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me - check your call statement (you seem to have a mismatch between the procedure name and the call statement) and data

```
drop table if exists book,author,wrote;
create table book (bookcode int,title varchar(10));
create table author(authornum int, authorfirst varchar(5));
create table wrote(bookcode int, authornum int);

insert into book values(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb');
insert into wrote values(1,1),(2,2);
insert into author values(1,'toni'),(2,'cyril');

drop procedure if exists func;

    delimiter ^^
    create procedure func(in authName varchar(20), out books varchar(255))
    begin
        select book.title
        into books
        from book
        INNER JOIN wrote on wrote.bookcode = book.bookcode
        INNER JOIN author on author.authornum = wrote.authornum    
        where authName = author.authorFirst;

    end ^^
    delimiter ;

call func('Toni', @books); 
select @books;

+--------+
| @books |
+--------+
| aaa    |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you, it's weird it ran for you, you are not using mysql right?